# how to redraw a control after I drag it out of screen in MFC

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I am new in MFC,I have a problem that I show a picture in pictute control but when I drag it out of screen,the part of picture disappear and don't redraw.
How to solve this problem,please?

Comment: The part of a window that comes (again) into view should normally be invalidated and consequently repainted (receiving a WM_PAINT message). This is the default behaviour. Maybe you are doing something custom or wrong. Provide us with some more information.

Comment: Show the relevant parts of your failing code.